# 2d Game graphics/sprites - landscape vs portrait - 2 sets?

Tags: iphone, graphics

I am working on a simple iPad game and wondering whether I should be using different graphics for portrait vs landscape or just doing some kind of transform between them?

Thanks for any tips/advice
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best answer is that it really depends on what game you make. If you want the graphics to be different, go for it. Otherwise, it is typical to use one set of graphics and maybe just organize the on-screen GUI differently. The screen is really just a viewport into the game world, and as its shape changes (from tall to wide), it should not affect the physics of the world; unless of course you WANT it to change the physics rules. It's really dependent on what game you are making.

Comment: Thanks - I just have little figures that move/can be moved around - but when rotated they come become short squat figures :)  Perhaps my rotation logic is not handling things correctly...

Comment: Ah, that explains your question then. Yes, it is definitely the case that your logic is not quite right... I have not done iPad development myself but it sounds like you are rotating the texture but not the geometry (vertices, triangles) in your code, however it is represented.